# Applying an IO redirection&audio device example in Fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, io-redirection, devices

Here is an example I saw in a webpage which uses IO redirection to make the audio device make sound.

```
less sound.wav > /dev/audio
```

But I cannot do it in Fedora. It outputs the input data format is wrong.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

`less` is a pager, typically used like `less file` to provide a scrollable view of the file's content, that is, a console user interface.  Thus redirecting the output of `less` doesn't make much sense.  The error you get, however, is because `less` is not good at displaying binary data, e.g. a `.wav` file.

If you want the *file's content* input into the device, `cat audio.wav > /dev/audio` is more promising, since `cat` does just that, print the file's content to stdout.  (I'm not sure if it works that way, though.)